# Android Crash while clicking the Button.

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

So, I'm kind of totally brand new to Android development and I'm trying to get my ball rolling with a decent dice-rolling app. I've had a look at the method that I'm calling and it doesn't seem that's the problem with my coding - but when I click one of these Image Buttons (I have some with identical coding, except for different dice numbers), the app freezes up and boots the device back to the menu (tested on Galaxy Nexus AVD and actual Samsung Galaxy S4 device). The code in question (defined in fragment_main.xml):

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/d4ImageButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:src="@drawable/d4"
    android:onClick="rolld4()" />
```

as well as the method it's attempting to call (defined in main_activity.java)

```
private int _dice; 

protected int dice() { 
return _dice; 
} 

 public void rolld4() { 
 Random rndGen = new Random(System.nanoTime()); 
 _dice = rndGen.nextInt(4); 
 }
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `android:onClick="rolld4()"` to `android:onClick="rolld4"`, and add the required `View` parameter to `rolld4()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/d4ImageButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:src="@drawable/d4"
    android:onClick="rolld4" />
```

Use `android:onClick="rolld4"`  instead of `android:onClick="rolld4()"` because  android:onClick only take function name without braces.